# selenium identify element with python 3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having problems to identify the following web element with selenium for python 3:

```
<button data-original-title="Reply" class="ProfileTweet-actionButton u-textUserColorHover js-actionButton js-actionReply js-tooltip" data-modal="ProfileTweet-reply" type="button">
```

Which method do i have to use?
What would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to find the element relying on different element attributes.

I'd rely on the `data-original-title` attribute and use [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-original-title="ProfileTweet-reply"]')
```

Or, use the `data-modal` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-modal="Reply"]')
```

Or, you can combine the expressions and make your own.

---

Another strategy and as an example of an alternative solution would be to use "CSS selectors" via [`find_element_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector), for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ProfileTweet-actionButton')
```

Comment: python keeps telling me that the element cant be found :-(

Comment: @123 are there `iframe` or `frame` elements on a page?

Comment: there are iframes elemets on the page.

Comment: @123 if this button is inside an iframe, first you need to switch to that iframe, e.g. `driver.switch_to.frame('frame_id_or_name')`.